# Find tags in text for replacement, my brute force solution

Tags: c#

I have a text such as

```
string text = "Hi [img-2] tst[img-3] test ttteessstt grawr[img-1-800]tet";
```

I want to find img tags in the text and get their id (second value) and possibly the third value if it exists.

```
string text = "Hi [img-2] tst[img-3] test ttteessstt grawr[img-1-800]tet";

var th = new TagHandler(null);
var res = th.FindImgTags(text);

foreach(var tag in res)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", tag.Tag, tag.Id, tag.Width));
}
```

The above code outputs this:

```
[img-2], 2, 0
[img-3], 3, 0
[img-1-800], 1, 800
```

This is my "find tags code". Its crude but gets the job done...
Any suggestions on how to make this less verbose / brute

```
public List<ImgReplaceItem> FindImgTags(string data)
{
    var result = new List<ImgReplaceItem>();

    var pieces = data.Split(new string[] { "[img-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (var item in pieces)
    {
        if (item.Contains(']'))
        {
            var backend = item.Split(new char[] { ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var dataInside = backend[0];

            var r = new ImgReplaceItem();
            r.Tag = "[img-" + dataInside + "]";
            var pid = -1;
            if (dataInside.Contains('-'))
            {
                var widthParts = dataInside.Split(new char[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                int.TryParse(widthParts[0], out pid);

                if (widthParts.Count() > 1)
                {
                    var width = -1;
                    int.TryParse(widthParts[1], out width);
                    r.Width = width;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int.TryParse(dataInside, out pid);
            }
            r.Id = pid;
            result.Add(r);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Heslacher I thought I give the OP a [chance](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140669/find-tags-in-text-for-replacement-my-brute-force-solution#comment263504_140670) to repair it by himself ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t since when are we a firendly community ? ;-) Just kidding. Nevertheless by adding the link to meta the reasons for the rollback are more clear.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Seems weird that I should post a new answer when the answer I would post is basically copy paste of @t3chb0t with minor edit for my purpose. But I guess that is a question for a different forum. I'll post the code as an answer when I get back to my dev machine again.

Comment: @JensB since it's not identical it's perfectly fine to post it as a self-anser. otherwise new visitors might want to review your reviewed code - this would be very confusing to everyone - a vicious circle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *a lot* of code for such a *simple* task... but how about some regex:

```
string text = "Hi [img-2] tst[img-3] test ttteessstt grawr[img-1-800]tet";

var ids = Regex.Matches(
     text, 
     @"\[(?<tag>[a-z]+)-(?<id>\d+)(-(?<width>\d+))?\]",
     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture
)
.Cast<Match>()
.Select(m => new ImgReplaceItem
{
    Tag = m.Groups["tag"].Value,
    Id = m.Groups["id"].Value,
    Width = m.Groups["width"].Success ? int.Parse(m.Groups["width"].Value) : 0   
});
```

result:

> ```
> Tag Id  Width
>
> img 2   0
> img 3   0
> img 1   800
> ```

---

As to the code. I think it's well writen. There isn't actually much to correct if anything.

Just a small adjustment:

> ```
> if (item.Contains(']'))
> ```

You could make it `!item.Contains(']')` and use the `contintue` to reduce nesting.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to use this instead, much more clear as to what is happening. Everytime I see regex solutions I think that they are great and want to learn Regex better..

Comment: @JensB I'm glad I could help ;-) I'd like you to ask to remove the edit from the question and post it as an answer instead.. you can mark it as a community-wiki. It's the preferred way for posting refactored code.